# Можно ли изменить index.html на index.php? (GitHub Pages)

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Кто знает такой сервис как GitHub Pages (хостинг гитхаба)? После загрузки репозитория при переходе по ссылке `username.github.io` выдает ошибку, т.к. не может найти `index.html` файл.
Как-то можно изменить эти настройки и ссылаться на `index.php`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. И нет - серверная часть github pages не предоставляет никаких мощностей, в том числе обработку со своей стороны php-кода (любого кода).Никаких настроек нет, ничего не поменяешь. Есть поддержка плагинов, также github pages умеют компилировать jekyll сайты (ну и другое). Но об этом сам найдешь.
Используй `index.html`.

Comment: Да, покопался немного в документации, действительно код не обрабатывается. Спасибо.

Comment: *Есть поддержка плагинов* в пределах довольно небольшого множества, и только для Jekyll, другие движки там не поддерживаются вовсе, разве что уже собранная статика.